# Can't find the meaning of these (*) pointer expressions

Tags: c

What does mean by these expression which I found somewhere and I can't find any effective search results to learn about them via examples or anything:

```
(*)[15]  //how is this defined/used
```

And

```
int (*fun)(int)[1]
```

The second one is a function pointer but what is meant by `[1]` at the end?

Comment: You might like the site cdecl.org, which translates between human-readable and C syntax. For example, your second declaration translates to "declare fun as pointer to function (int) returning array 1 of int"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
      fun          // fun is...
     *fun          // a pointer to...
    (*fun)
    (*fun)(int)    // a function with an `int` parameter, returning...
    (*fun)(int)[1] // an array of size 1 of ...
int (*fun)(int)[1] // int
```

Functions can't return arrays, so this type is invalid and can't be used in a C program.

Comment: And what will this do `(*)[15]`

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus A pointer to an array of size 15 to (you need to add a type on the left). Variable name goes after the `*`.